# Installing ruby gem from git repository failed: rake aborted

Tags: ruby, git, rubygems

I cloned a git repository successfully to my local machine but I cant install the gem..
(I installed rake 10.1.0), also the dependent gem *oauth* is installed

```
    git clone git://github.com/marcel/twurl.git
    rake gem --trace
```

Error message:

```
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'gem'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task_manager.rb:49:in `[]'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:148:in `invoke_task'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `top_level'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `top_level'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:165:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.1.0/bin/rake:33
/usr/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/usr/bin/rake:19
```

I appreciate your help!

Comment: What gem you want to install? This isn't how you install ruby gems.

Comment: I want to install twurl from the github source (https://github.com/marcel/twurl/blob/master/INSTALL)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
gem build twurl.gemspec
```

instead of

```
rake gem
```

The error message clearly states, that the `Rakefile` has no task named `gem`.

After you have the `gem` built, install it with `gem install`.

Comment: 'rake install' task does the same in easy way

Comment: @crackedmind You are surely right. But I did not take a look at `Rakefile`, plus the long way through `gem` executions shows what’s really being happened.